# Does Chromium support intercept WebWorker requests via CDP?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chromium, web-worker, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to intercept WebWorker requests by sending `Fetch.enable` in a worker target session, but got a `"'Fetch.enable' wasn't found"` error from Chromium. Does that mean Chromium not support WebWorker request interception? My Chromium version is `97.0.4691.0 (Developer Build)`.

A reasonable answer would be greatly appreciated.

--Update--
I guess I've got it worked in the puppeteer way. Please check out my fix [kitt1987/puppeteer](https://github.com/kitt1987/puppeteer/commit/dddff4aed4f2241832e620b1cd6811da7394dfca). Just a quick fix, not well-designed.

**TL;NR**

Actually, I intercepted requests of a website using puppeteer. Then I found that this site requests some files in WebWorker but puppeteer has bugs if the interception is enabled. See [puppeteer/puppeteer#4208](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4208) and [puppeteer/puppeteer#2781](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2781).

After digging in puppeteer source code and tracing raw protocol messages, it seems that calling `page.setRequestInterception(true)` also intercepts WebWorker requests, but **these requests never issue any `Network.requestWillBeSent` events**, which is known as `page.request` events in puppeteer, then WebWorker requests hang for waiting for a `request.continue()` which is usually called in the `page.request` event handler.

Then I tried to figure out why `Network.requestWillBeSent` events were lost. Chrome DevTools is able to trace all requests in its network panel, then I analyzed its CDP traffic in [Protocol Monitor](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#protocol-monitor) and found that a new WebWorker started a new session, it needs to send `Network.enable` again in the new session to enable network tracing. But, after I send `Fetch.enable` in the new session to enable interception, the error arose.

```
  puppeteer:protocol:SEND ► {"sessionId":"3DE89BAC041203C90EF1B3D2CC348EAA","method":"Fetch.enable","params":{"handleAuthRequests":true,"patterns":[{"urlPattern":"*"}]},"id":245} +0ms
  puppeteer:protocol:RECV ◀ {"id":245,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'Fetch.enable' wasn't found"},"sessionId":"3DE89BAC041203C90EF1B3D2CC348EAA"} +0ms
```

You can find my fix in [kitt1987/puppeteer](https://github.com/kitt1987/puppeteer/commit/b40729d53984b920a951975c145f38a3a9b8bd13).

Comment: Having the same issue. I was able to listen to `Target.attachedToTarget` and in this I send a command `Network.enable` to the targetId came from this event. but I still see the same behavior where Network.requestWillBeSent is not showing.

Comment: Maybe [Selenium-Interceptor](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Interceptor) helps you as a starting point :)