# puppeteer: How to intercept ServiceWorker/WebWorker request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

There are some old solutions to resolve this question, the one is in [github](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4041#issuecomment-469496322), the other is in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645680/does-chromium-support-intercept-webworker-requests-via-cdp).

`puppeteer` has `_client` property in lower version.
The solution in lower vision as follows:

```
page._client.send('Network.setBypassServiceWorker', {bypass: true})
```

The puppeteer version is `18.0.5`, so the `Page` has not `_client` property.

So the same solution in higher vison as follows:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send("Network.setBypassServiceWorker", { bypass: true });
```

But it not working.
So how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should add a new line `await client.send("Network.enable")` to enable the network. The code as follows:

```
...
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send("Network.enable");  // Must enable network.
await client.send("Network.setBypassServiceWorker", { bypass: true });
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
...
```

So we can handle the response in `page.on()`.

```
...
page.on("response", async (res) => {
    // do somethings.
})
...
```

Comment: You don't need to touch CDP at all. For me `await page.setRequestInterception(true)` is just enough on puppeteer-core 20.4.0